# Detected overlapping in SQL, without using a subquery in the select and without adding duplicate records to the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm looking to create a query that can detected overlapping in SQL, without using a subquery in the select and without adding duplicate records to the result set.

I know it can be done like this, but considering the amount of records in both tables I'm looking for faster solution.

```
SELECT x.T1Id
    ,CASE 
        WHEN MaxOtherColumn IS NULL
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END HasOverlapInT2
    ,CASE 
        WHEN MaxOtherColumn IS NULL
            THEN OtherColumn
        ELSE MaxOtherColumn
        END MaxOtherColumn
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT MAX(T2.OtherColumn)
                    FROM T2
                    WHERE T1.ValidFrom <= T2.ValidUntil
                        AND T2.ValidFrom <= T1.ValidUntil
                        AND t1.T1Id = T2.T1Id
                    )
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END MaxOtherColumn
        ,T1Id
        ,OtherColumn
    FROM T1
    ) x
```

I don't want to perform the exists for each row, but process it in batch.

## Sample data

### Table 1

| T1Id (PK) | ValidFrom | ValidUntil | OtherColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-09-23 | 2021-09-24 | 2 |

### Table 2

| T2Id (PK) | T1Id(FK) | ValidFrom | ValidUntil | OtherColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-05-31 | 9000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-12-31 | 9001 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-05 | 7000 |

## Expected result

| T1Id | HasOverlapInT2 | MaxOtherColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9001 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 |

*SQL server compatibility level = 130 (2016)*

Comment: Like most professional SQL DBMSs, SQL Serever has a state of the art statistical optimizer, so good/bad performance of a query is not determined by the presence/absence of subqueries.  If you have a query that is too slow, then post the query plan, and table definitions along with some indication of how much faster you need it to be.

Comment: The query you have doesn't produce the expected result, so let's solve that before we try to optimize performance: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c781ffa54386331131c8ceb6359581d5

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CROSS APPLY` to achieve your expected result (your current solution doesn't return your expected results):

```
SELECT x.T1Id,
    CASE 
        WHEN MaxOtherColumn IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END HasOverlapInT2,
    CASE 
        WHEN MaxOtherColumn IS NULL
        THEN OtherColumn
        ELSE MaxOtherColumn
    END MaxOtherColumn
FROM
(
    SELECT t.MaxOtherColumn,
        T1Id,
        OtherColumn
    FROM T1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT MAX(T2.OtherColumn) MaxOtherColumn
        FROM T2
        WHERE T1.ValidFrom <= T2.ValidUntil
        AND T2.ValidFrom <= T1.ValidUntil
        AND t1.T1Id = T2.T1Id
    ) t
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way to think about it, in case `APPLY` is too mind-bending:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT T1.T1Id, 
    T2Other = T2.OtherColumn, 
    T1Other = T1.OtherColumn,
    Overlap = CASE WHEN T2.ValidUntil >= T1.ValidFrom
              AND T2.ValidFrom <= T1.ValidUntil THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 END
  FROM dbo.T1
  INNER JOIN dbo.T2
    ON T1.T1Id = T2.T1Id
)
SELECT T1Id, 
  HasOverlapInT2 = MAX(Overlap), 
  MaxOtherColumn = MAX(CASE Overlap WHEN 1 THEN T2Other ELSE T1Other END)
FROM src
GROUP BY T1Id;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c5a1c4b79948934631ddfce46de5add8)

The key is to think about a way to generate the results with a single pass of both. While a correlated subquery doesn't always mean worse performance,  it *can* lead to a scan of one table for every row in the other.

Comment: Imo cte's are much more mind-bending but I guess that's just because I haven't used them very often.

Comment: @diiN__________ I think recursive CTEs can be mind-bending; this is just slightly different syntax for a derived table, ordered logically in a way that makes you think of the derived table first. It would be easy to rewrite without a CTE (e.g. by using `FROM (<cte contents>) AS src`, or by putting the code in the CTE in a view.